# Linkedin Social Media Signup Blocked

Tags: linkedin-api, omniauth-linkedin

We have a platform that allows visitors to the site to signup with Linkedin as well as other social media platforms. We setup the Oauth for this more than a year ago and it worked fine for about a year. A few weeks ago, we were testing to launch and saw a popup that says the 'application is disabled'.

After testing from different devices, the 'Application is disabled' popup still shows when a visitor clicks Signup with Linkedin.

I tested on Firefox and Chrome. We removed a Chrome extension as we thought that was causing the issue but that did not resolve the problem.

I googled it but no useful suggestions come up. Seems like is an unusual problem. I raised a ticket with Linkedin and they pointed me to Stack Overflow.

So here I am looking for help. If anyone has experienced this issue, I appreciate help to resolve. Thanks for any help.